# Как правильно настроить UrlManager?

Tags: yii2

Использую advanced, настраиваю UrlManager в common/config/main.php следующим образом

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules'=>[
            '/' => 'site/index',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ]

    ],
```

потом пытаюсь использовать так

```
<li><a href="<?= Yii::$app->urlManager->createUrl(['/blog/list']) ?>">Блог</a></li>
```

выдает адрес http://blog/list (то есть без доменного имени). Объясните что я делаю не так? И как правильно настроить что бы адрес был условно http://mysite/blog/list (ну или на худой конец http://mysite/frontend/web/blog/list.
 вот .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
    RewriteRule ^admin/assets/(.*)$ backend/web/assets/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^admin/css/(.*)$ backend/web/css/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/backend/web/(assets|css)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(admin)
RewriteRule ^.*$ backend/web/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(assets|css|js|images)
RewriteRule ^assets/(.*)$ frontend/web/assets/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^css/(.*)$ frontend/web/css/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^js/(.*)$ frontend/web/js/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^images/(.*)$ frontend/web/images/$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ frontend/web/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(frontend|backend)/web/(assets|css|js)/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ frontend/web/index.php
```

вот frontend/config/main.php

```
'request' => [
            'baseUrl' => '/'
        ],
```

вот frontend/web/.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
      Options -Indexes
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
      Options +FollowSymlinks
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
      RewriteRule . index.php
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Зачем вы всю логику описываете в .htaccess? Вот как решить текущую задачу:

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
# If a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

UrlManager в web.php

```
 'urlManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
        // Disable index.php
        'showScriptName' => false,
        // Disable r= routes
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'rules' => array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ),
    ],
```

и пример линка

```
<a href="<? echo Url::to(['blog/list']) ?>">Линк</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

baseUrl - убираем слеш радуемся. А то он поднимает вверх по каталогу, добавляя второй слеш. Получается //controller/action, где контроллер становится именем домена. Как-то так.